# Last hour wise count from 00 AM to last hour - mysql

Tags: mysql

I trying to fetch count of records from 00 AM i.e. 12 to last hour group by Hours.

```
select count(RESPONSE) AS TOTAL_521_ERROR from Sale_GT 
where ERRORCODE='521' 
AND SALEDATE > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

This query fetching last one hour record. similary I want if i run query at 5 AM then result should be `count(RESPONSE)` from 00 AM to 4 AM `group by HOUR(SALEDATE)`.

Hour  Count
0      345
1      432
2      36
3      87
4      90

so result will be from 12 night to last hour of query execution time.

Please help.

Comment: Its not very clear what you are trying to do from your description. Can you try and edit you question please. Some examples of times and results expected at those times would be good. PS: Edit the question dont post this as comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SELECT` with `GROUP BY`, e.g.:

```
SELECT HOUR(SALEDATE) AS `hour`, COUNT(RESPONSE) AS `errors` 
FROM Sale_GT 
WHERE ERRORCODE='521' 
AND SALEDATE >= DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY `hour`;
```

Comment: No It is fetching only last hour records. I want if I run query at any hour like 7 PM then results will be from 12 at night to 6 PM group by HOUR

Comment: It is worked. Still it is fetching current hours as well. like i run at 16:23 so after group by there is 16 hour as well with time 16:22. But no issue It will work. Thanks

Comment: @ketanpatil you can accept the answer if it has helped you.